# Long-term search trends by domain

Tags: tool-request, trends

I want to know what people are searching for in a particular domain (the domain is enterprise software, if that matter). The goal is to discover new trends.

I tried the [Hot Trends](https://www.google.com/trends/hottrends) feature which is part of the Google Trends tools, but unfortunately:

- It only gives trends for the last 24 hours.
- No way to divide by domain, so all results are sports/politics and other topics more popular than the particular domain I am interested in.

Is there a trends viewing tool that fits my requirements?

Trends could be measured with another metric such as hashtags or word use, but I would prefer the *number of searches* metric.

Open data would be the best, but *just free* is OK too.

Example usage:

> Me: What are the top trending searches in **enterprise software** in **2016**?
>   The service: **Nuxeo** (3m searches), **Salesforce** (700k searches), etc

Comment: There are some unofficial APIs - does that help? e.g. https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends

Comment: @philshem: This tool covers only one function of Google Trends, which requires to know the search terms already. Unfortunately I don't know the search terms, my goal is to discover them, I edited my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this open source library in node: https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-trends-api

It seems to have several Google trends functions available.

Comment: Nothing gives long-term search by domain, according to the documentation, or did I miss it? The nearest would be `topRelated` which does not seem to cover a domain. If I missed a better function please specify it thanks!